# Allow a C++ abstract class to use an Objective-C delegate

Tags: c++, ios, delegates, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and his concrete class implementation.
What I would like to do is to expose the concrete class inside an iOS application (Objective-C) and use protocols to dispatch the events to a ViewController.

The idea is to add an objective C delegate, that conforms an adHoc protocol, to this concrete Class.
Any Idea how to achieve it?

Unfortunately I read that Objective-C++ cannot inherits from a C++ class.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: an objective c++ class cant inherit from a c++ class but it can contain one

Comment: @RichardHodges that was exactly the issue. Can you write it as an answer please?

Comment: done. glad it helped.

Comment: I find this question is a little confusing. Are you saying you want the C++ class to contain the Obj-C delegate? Or you wish the C++ class to act as a delegate?

Answer (score 1):

an objective c++ class can't inherit from a c++ class but it can contain one

```
@interface DelegateObject : NSObject
{
}
- (id) init;
- (void) do_something: (NSObject*) thing;
@end

struct cpp_thing
{
    // this could be a template if you wished, or you could take a copy
    // or whatever you want
    void do_something(NSObject* thing) { };
};

@implementation DelegateObject
{
    std::shared_ptr<cpp_thing> _cpp;
}

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _cpp = std::make_shared<cpp_thing>();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) do_something: (NSObject*) thing
{
    _cpp->do_something(thing);
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you also tell us how to implement delegation functionality between Objective-C and C++?

Answer (score 0):

Try a has-a relationship.  Either the objective C++ object has-a  C++ object or vice versa.  Then make them aware of each other enough for the objective C++ object to relay messages to the C++ object.

Comment: Sorry if I'm late but I was really busy. 
Could you explain better? I did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you declared a weak pointer to id, you could declare an abstract delegate (a category in NSObject), then call methods freely in the CPP source.  Simply import the file that contains the abstract delegate then implement the methods themselves in the ObjC class, and you get a delegate without declaring an actual delegate.

Comment: This seems a good trick. I'll try it.
In this moment I solved creating a custom Class very similar to the NSNotificationCenter. The main difference is that this class is able to handle the object:(void*) field with a void* variable instead of an id object. 
In this way I'm able to observe for a particular notification submitted by my concrete C++ class implantation.
The concrete class submits to the custom notification center an event
An objective c object is now able to observe for notification submitted by any kind of object (void*). 
What do you think about this strategy?