# Getting C++ model to inform Objective-C++ controller via delegation method

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I have programmed a chess game **model** in C++. Now, I want an Objective-C++ **controller** to initialize a **model** object and become it's delegate.

Therefore, when the **model** finishes it's task, it should inform the **controller** and **controller** should update the **view**.

Now when I instantiate the C++ **model** like this:

```
Model *model = new Model();
model->delegate = self;
```

in Objective-C++. It gives me this error:

```
Assigning to 'Delegate *' from incompatible type 'NSObject *const __strong'
```

From what I have understood, I need to make the type of delegate to be an anonymous container (or object of type NSObject).

What is the best solution when you're connecting different languages like this?

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I found a work around but now I am having memory management problems. The Objective-C object I am storing gets released when it exits the scope. Here is the code:

```
struct SharedObjectiveCObject {
Class sharedObjectiveCObject;
public:
    SharedObjectiveCObject() : sharedObjectiveCObject([GameViewController class]) {}
};



class Controller {

private:
    GameViewController *gameViewController; // THIS GETS RELEASED ON EXITING SCOPE (THIS IS AN OBJECT OF OBJECTIVE-C CLASS)

public:
     Controller() {
        std::unique_ptr<SharedObjectiveCObject> sharedObjectiveCObject(new SharedObjectiveCObject());

        this->gameViewController = (__bridge GameViewController*)(sharedObjectiveCObject.get()); // THIS GETS RELEASED ON EXITING SCOPE
    }
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

In other words, I have the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638459/allow-a-c-abstract-class-to-use-an-objective-c-delegate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate needs to be an Objective C class implementing the appropriate delegate protocol; you can't just stick in a C++ object.  My solution was creating a "relay" class initialized with a pointer to the C++ object that's the real target of the message.  When a delegate method is invoked, it performs a function call on the C++ object.

An example can be found in the project [pianod2](http://deviousfish.com/pianod2/), in source file src/mediaunits/audio/osxplayer.mm.  The class PlayerHelper provides the shim between delegates of both AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem (from AVFoundation framework) and the C++ type AVFoundationPlayer, also defined in osxplayer.mm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked your code, you are assigning a C++ object to an Objective-C property. I want to do the exact opposite of it, I want to store an Objective-C reference in C++ so whenever I want, I can just send delegate messages to it. That's what I want. An Objective-C object to send messages to anytime I want without knowing it's type.

Comment: I tried something else. It worked but now I am having memory management problems because the Objective-C object I am storing gets released. It doesn't get retained for long. Kindly see the edit.

Comment: You're putting a value in the unique_ptr, then *copying* it out with .get().  This leaves the pointer in the hands of unique_ptr, to be destroyed when it goes out of scope.  Use .release() instead, which *moves* the pointer instead.